# Automator action with variable number of parameters

Tags: xcode, action, automator

I am trying to create an Automator action to do stored procedure calls in MySQL.  I would like to be able to specify an arbitrary number of parameters.  The *Get Specified Finder Items* action can accept an arbitrary number of files, but it is not clear how I do this in my own action.  If I place an NSTableView on the UI Automator seems to hang when I test adding it to a workflow.  I am also not clear even if I did get this to work what would show up in the parameters.

I am running OS X 10.8.4 (Mountain Lion), XCode 4.6.3, Automator 2.3 (346).

Thanks for any insight.